# URL rewrite conflicting rules

Tags: .htaccess

I'm having problems getting my URL rewrite to work, I currently have these 3 rules

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
```

and I want to add a rule where if the user hits http://example.com/metrics/, it sends them to index.php?/sign-in

I've tried doing `RewriteRule /metrics/(.*) /index.php?/sign-in [PT]`, but it seems to be conflicting with the .* rule and not sending the user to /index.php?/sign-in at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you have logically conflicting rules, put the more specific before the more general.

For your purpose, something like this should work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^metrics/?(.*)$ /index.php?/sign-in [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
```

As an aside, you may want to consider revising your approach.

What if the user is already signed in? Perhaps, your `/metrics` page should behave (.htaccess wise) the same as your other pages, and have its code do the equivalent of `if( !SignedIn() ) Redirect( "/sign-in" )` in your language of choice.